# How to select geo when you have a component of that geo?

Tags: python, maya, pymel

How do you get the name of a piece of geo when all you have is a component of that geo (uvs, faces, verts, edges)?

so for example I have:

```
MeshVertex(u'pCubeShape1.vtx[0]') #replace that with any of the following (uvs, faces, edges)
```

and what I would like to end up with is:

```
nt.Transform(u'pCube1')
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You can do this both with [**cmds.ls**](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2013/en_us/CommandsPython/ls.html)  (if I'm not terribly mistaken with geometry flag, no Maya at hand) and with [**cmds.listRelatives**](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2013/en_us/CommandsPython/listRelatives.html)

Comment: @joojaa just tested and neither seems to be working.

Comment: Ah sorry you were using pymel

Comment: @TheBeardedBerry if by geo you mean geometry then please edit the question replacing geo with geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say `vtx = MeshVertex(u'pCubeShape1.vtx[0]')`

then the transform/geo can be found using:

```
import pymel.core as pc
transforms = pc.listTransforms(vtx.node())
transform = transforms[0] #in case there is only one.
```

Answer (score 1):

As your example, let's say `v = MeshVertex(u'pCubeShape1.vtx[0]')`

```
import pymel.core as pm
transform = v.node().getParent()
select(transform)
```

I know this question has already been answered, but I thought I'd post my way of doing this so that others can see different ways :)

Hope this helps